# Border of image clipped by Bezier path

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, clip

Suppose I have an image that was rendered by drawing another image into it with a Bezier path used to clip the drawing. What I'd like is to be able to render the resulting image in such a way that the edges of the new image look like they're beveled. I'm thinking that something that draws the Bezier path with some line thickness that varies the color with the angle of the path is what I want. Is there a function that automates this process? I'm thinking there must be, or else there wouldn't be such an array of buttons and so forth that are rendered this way.

The app icons, for example, are an illustration of what I'm looking for. They have a sort of drop shadow on the lower right and a highlight at upper left.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a beveling algorithm for reasonably simple shapes.  The algorithm will take a closed path, bevel it (45° inset) and then apply provided highlight/shadow colors given a specific light source angle.  It's not perfect and on really complex shapes you may not get the effect you desire, but I've found it works on most "normal" shapes (squares, circles, triangles, round-rects, and even stars, gears and some slightly more complex shapes).  The algorithm will attempt to apply the highlight/shadows by calculating where the other sides of the path intersect with the light rays of the light source.  I've written a blog post about it here: http://aaronhayman.com/2012/beveling-shapes-in-core-graphics/, but the blog post is a little out of date from the actual code, which I've improved since I first wrote that post.  You can find the code here: https://gist.github.com/ahayman/2830483.  The code is written in straight "c", and is designed to be as fast and compact as possible.

A few things to note:

- If you're beveling a CGPath for an Image (as mentioned), consider passing in highlight/shadow colors with a semi-tranparent alpha.  For example the following colors would create a subtle bevel effect:

`UIColor *highlight = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.25f];`

`UIColor *shadow = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.25f];`

- Note that this algorithm won't bevel the image itself (or bend the image to look bevelled).  It simply draws a bevel in the shape.  Actually bending the image would require Core Image.  However, if you use transparency it can look as though there is a transparent bevel on top of the image.  That may be enough.

**Alternative**

You can also cheat a little and draw a gradient in a stroked path.  I think a lot of people don't ever notice this little Core Graphics function but `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath` is a fantastic little function.  In effect, it lets you create a new path by stroking another path.  You can then take the returned path and apply a gradient to it to create a "bevelled look".  As an example, let say I have a `UIBezierPath *path` variable that represents the bezier path you want to bevel.

```
        UIBezierPath *path = [self imageClippingPath];
        CGPathRef stroke = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(path.CGPath, NULL, 2.0f, path.lineCapStyle, path.lineJoinStyle, path.miterLimit);
        UIBezierPath *strokedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:stroke];
        [self drawGradientInPath:strokedPath inContext:context];
        CGPathRelease(stroke);
```

Note that if you clip to the path, you'll get a stroke that is only 1.0f wide, since strokes are made *around* the path and the clip will cut the stroke in half.

You can create an even better "bevel" by creating two separate stroked paths of different widths: say an "inner" bevel with a width of 4.0f and an "outer" bevel with a width of 2.0f.  You would first draw the "inner" bevel and then layer the outer bevel (which is half the width of the inner) over it.  If you also clip your context to the path you're stroking, you would end up two separate bevels, each 1.0f in size. Remember that strokes are made *around* the path.  So only half the stoke will be inside the clipped area.  If you fill in the inner bevel with a different gradient than the out bevel, you can create an inset-button-look that mimics many of Apple's own.  After looking closely at Apple's buttons, I'm pretty sure this is exactly what they do (or something very similar) to get a bevelled look.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions. I will try out your second suggestion. I've already tried something similar but without the gradient

Comment: Hmmm. If this is going to work, I think I'll have to use the individual Bezier curves rather than the whole curve consisting of concatenated curves. This is because the joined curve forms a closed loop. The result seems to be that when setting a clip, it's not the original path that is inside the clip area but the space the path encloses. I hope that makes sense. The good news is that I was going to use the individual Bezier curves anyway, in order to be able to apply gradients that made sense. I think I'll table this for now and concentrate on more pressing issues in the app.

Comment: I found this old post (because it's a popular question, apparently) and realized I hadn't accepted an answer. I was going to accept this answer, but the links in it are broken. If you update it, I can accept it. Or I will add my own answer later with what I wound up actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you're looking for. You can use a 2D convolution kernel, similar to what's described [in this article](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html).

I'm not sure if it's available on iOS, but Core Image come with the [CIHeightFieldFromMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) filter, which produces something like what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure how those articles apply to my question. What I'm looking for is something that operates on a CGPath or UIBezierCurve, not on image content.

Comment: They produce a result that sounds like what you're looking for if you do them right. But given your attitude, maybe what you want instead is the [Medial Axis Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis). It's significantly harder to calculate, but allows you to create a true bevel for any shape. Good luck!

Comment: Attitude? I simply didn't understand how your answer applied to my question and sought clarification. Who is "they", by the way?

Comment: After thinking about this some more, I see how the 2D convolution kernel could work if I used an image with a solid fill of the bezier path. A problem, though, is that it is raster based, rather than vector based, so would be resolution-dependent.